# In newLISP, quote is different from '?

Tags: newlisp

I begin to learn newlisp, but the quote and ' puzzle me.

```
> (= '(quote 1) ''1)  
nil
```

or

```
> (first (quote (quote 1)))  
quote

> (first ''1)  
ERR: array, list or string expected in function first : ''1
```

in newlisp, quote is different from ' ?
or, this is a bug?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had remembered newlisp was Common Lisp-conforming, but it's not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between the two. The single quote is resolved during source code translation, when the quoted cell is wrapped into a protecting envelope. The function `quote` does the same but during evaluation. For most purposes they behave in the same way.

So the function `quote` is more like the original Lisp `quote`. The `'` is an optimization performed during code translation. If you want to know more about code translation and evaluation, compare the functions `read-expr` and `eval-string`.

Comment: I read the newlisp's source, the **quote** is translated as a SYMBOL, but **'** is translated as a QUOTE.  I do the same thing, CL and Schme can return the quote,  `(car ''a)`  so, why newlisp do this?

Comment: There are many differences between Lisps... :) As for "why", your best bet might be to email the author of newLISP or ask at the newLISP forum.